# Getting the last child in a self-referencing hierachical tree

Tags: c#, relationship, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have the following type:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Top level categories have a `ParentId` value of 0. Any child categories are related to their respective parent via the `ParentId` property.

I'm trying to implement a nice way of determining which is the last child in the tree (however deep that tree is), so in the following example, I would expect to have the 'Laptops' entry returned (or its Id at least):

> **Id**: 10 **ParentId**: 0 **Title**: For Sale
>
> **Id**: 5 **ParentId**: 10 **Title**: Computers
>
> **Id**: 20 **ParentId**: 5 **Title**: Laptops

i.e. The hierachy being 'For Sale' > 'Computers' > 'Laptops'.

This hierachy may only consist of 1 Category OR it may in some cases have 5+ children.

Comment: What are your speed / memory limitations? You can either use DFS or recursion

Comment: Can you define last a bit more precisely? Is that the last child in any branch (since each branch can have multiple children), or the deepest child?

Comment: wait... do you have all the items in a list or just the root category?

Comment: I'm dealing with the same structure, but (argh!) in PHP/Javascript/MySql. I added a couple of useful parameters: "order of visualization" and "branch-id". Then I made IP-like dotted codes (they are unique) simply chaining all the "branch-id"s. In your case "1.5.20.3.12" could be "for sale - computer - laptop - IBM - Thinkpad", but it's easier to know how many 1.5.20 or 1.5.20.3 you have.

Comment: 'in a self-referencing hierachical tree' ie do you mean a graph ( ie a can be a parent of b is a parent of c is a parent of a)? if so what does 'last' mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LINQ, you can achieve this simply like this:

```
var LeafNodes = YourItemsList.Where(x => !YourItemsList.Any(y => y.ParentID == x.Id));
```

Now you can iterate over this enumerable and for each item, you can walk up the parent nodes to get the full chain.

Comment: This is doing a linear search of the list for every item in this list, which scales *very* poorly with the size of the collection.

Comment: @Servy: Hmmm... OP said he can have upto 5+ items per category, so he's not missing much more than a few microseconds with it, I guess. For larger lists however your point is very valid.

Comment: Each category has up to 5 children.  But if there are 1,000 categories that this operation is performed on...

Answer (score 2):

By creating a lookup with the parent Id as the key you can easily find all children for a given node, allowing you to easily find all nodes without any children.

```
var lookup = categories.ToLookup(category => category.ParentId);
var leaves = categories.Where(category => !lookup[category.Id].Any());
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ, you can achieve this simply like this:

```
var filteredData = parentChildData.Where(x => (parentChildData.All(y => y.ParentId != x.Id))).ToList();
```

Comment: Why do you preferred this over the existing answers?